# Изменения счетчика цикла for

Tags: python

Можно ли в цикле for изменять значения счетчика? К примеру:

```
for i in range(10): 
   if(i==5):
      i=8
```

Но при достижении i 5 значение на 8 не меняется. Начиная с новой итерации i, как и планировалось изначально, будет 6. Есть ли способы преодоления этого ограничения? Или только цикл while использовать для таких ситуаций?

Answer (score 4):

```py
from itertools import chain

ranges = range(5), range(8, 10)

for i in chain.from_iterable(ranges):
    print(i)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 3):

С помощью цикла `for` мы можем выполнить набор операторов один раз для `каждого` элемента в списке,
кортеже, и т.д.

С помощью оператора `continue` мы можем остановить текущую итерацию цикла и продолжить следующую:

```
for i in range(10): 
    if i == 5 or i == 6 or i == 7:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Comment: можно `if 5 <= i <= 7`. Правда, долго будет перещелкиваться если большой интервал.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru можно

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `while` вместо `for`:

```
i = 0
while i<10:
    if i==5:
        i = 8
    # ваш код
    i += 1
```

Comment: Блин, смотрю первый ответ — не такой, как я хочу написать, второй — тоже, и третий, и тут смотрю четвертый таки такой. XD

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, да самое то. И зачем `Topinambur` без `while` понадобилось?

Answer (score 2):

Саму переменную цикла менять без толку - на каждой новой итерации цикла `for` ей будет присвоено значение очередной итерации и все ваши изменения забудутся. Можно только пропустить какие-то значения с помощью `continue`, например, так:

```
for i in range(10): 
   if i in range(5, 8):
      continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто объединить интервалы:

```py
print(*(i for i in list(range(5)) + list(range(8, 10))))
```

или так

```py
for i in [*range(5),*range(8, 10)]:
    print(i)
```

или так

```py
from itertools import chain
for i in chain(range(5), range(8, 10)):
    print(i)
```

... или

```py
for i in set(range(10)).symmetric_difference(set(range(5,8))):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: print(*range(5),*range(8, 10))

Comment: @Danis, да, и так работает, вариантов - множество. От i только избавились.